# Remove selected class applied to list item by arrow key navigation when mouse hover style is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When UP/DOWN Arrow key is pressed in text box, selected class is applied to the list item. If I move the mouse pointer over list item and press up/down arrow key at the same time, both hover and selected class is applied to the list item. How to switch hover and selected class similar to select input option?

http://jsfiddle.net/AyAZx/790/

```js
$('#college').keyup(function(e) {

  var $listItems = $('.field-wrap li');
  var key = e.keyCode,
    $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
    $current;

  $listItems.removeClass('selected');


  var menu = $('#college_list');
  var height = $selected.outerHeight();
  var top = menu.scrollTop();
  var menuHeight = menu[0].scrollHeight;

  if (key == 40) // Down key
  {
    if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child')) {
      $current = $listItems.eq(0);
      menu.scrollTop(0);
    } else {
      $current = $selected.next();
      menu.scrollTop(top + height);
    }

    $current.addClass('selected');
  }

  if (key == 38) // Up key
  {
    if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child')) {
      $current = $listItems.last();
      menu.scrollTop(menuHeight + height);
    } else {
      $current = $selected.prev();
      menu.scrollTop(top - height);
    }
    $current.addClass('selected');
  }

});
```

```css
.field-wrap ul {
  width: 93%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #3498DB;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background: white;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.field-wrap ul li {
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
}
.field-wrap ul li:hover {
  background: #2980B9;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-wrap">
  <input type="text" id="college" placeholder="Name" required autocomplete="off" />
  <ul id="college_list">
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>def</li>
    <li>asdff</li>
    <li>dasdf</li>
    <li>asdef</li>
    <li>asdf</li>
    <li>asf</li>
    <li>asdef</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid in this case you will have to replace the css :hover with the mousemove event:

```
$('#college_list li').mousemove(function() {
   $('.field-wrap li').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This works fine in JSFiddle. But when I run the code(removed hover css) in chrome browser, initially when I move mouse pointer in list selected class is not getting applied. After pressing Up/Down key mouse pointer(hover) is working as expected.

Comment: Well i tested it in Chrome and it works fine for me .. Maybe putting the js part into $(window).ready(function() { ... }); helps you

Comment: I found the reason why its not working for me. I am retrieving the li item based on keyup events(AJAX Livesearch) from database. li items will be fetched dynamically & returned ( echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['college_name']).'\')">'.$college_name.'</li>';) each time a key is pressed. If I place mousemove function out of keyup event function mousemove function is not at all getting executed. But if I place it inside keyup event function and press up/down key for first time mousemove function is working. Is there any solution to solve this problem?